# force SSL and no WWW on Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, no-www

I'm having trouble coming up with the proper syntax to accomplish both forcing the SSL and no WWW.

**EDIT**

I've been able to accomplish each task separately but when combining the two i find myself stuck in a redirection loop.

working syntax to force no WWW:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My attempt to force no WWW and SSL

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SSL you could use something like:

```
Redirect / https://domain.com/
```

Place this only in the section of your virtual host you configure for HTTP, not HTTPS, to not run clients into endless loops.

Answer (score 0):

By 'no WWW' I assume you mean you want to remove any 'WWW.' prefix of the hostname?  Try this:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(?:www\.)?(.*)"  [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTPS}"     "=on"
RewriteRule "(.*)"         "https://%1$1"     [R=301,L]
```

If you're doing this in a `.htaccess` file, change that last line to

```
RewriteRule "(.*)"         "https://%1/$1"    [R=301,L]
```

If you want to be able to remove the 'WWW.' prefix regardless of SSL-ness or not, try this:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(?:www\.)?(.*)"  [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTPS}"     "=on"
RewriteRule "(.*)"         "https://%1/$1"    [R=301,L]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(?:www\.)?(.*)"  [NC]
RewriteRule "(.*)"         "http://%1/$1"     [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @RoUS I was unable to get either of these examples to work properly.

Comment: @Stephen What happened, precisely?  (/me goes to verify)

Comment: @RoUS Absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Okey, I'm trying to get my test system going again.  I'll comment shortly.

Comment: @RoUS for the record i AM using .htaccess

Comment: @Stephen Ah.  And did you change the 'http://%1$1' to 'http://%1/$1' ?  Do you have access to the Apache logs?

Comment: @RoUS Yes, I did change the rules as you suggested.

Comment: @Stephen Try the modified rules I put in my answer.

Comment: @RoUS Still nothing. fyi, you don't need the quotes to encapsulate the conditions/rules

Comment: @Stephen 
Yes, I know the quotes are unnecessary. I prefer to use them to make it clear where the parameters begin and end. So you don't get a redirect for `http://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com` ?

(comment reposted because the URIs were gobbled)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using on one of my sites - it seems to work a little better than most of the other methods I've seen:

```
  # The code below tells apache to always require secure (ssl/tls) connections
  # to the website. If a client tries connecting over port 80 (http://),
  # then the client will be redirected to https:// (over port 443).
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.0
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

For the no-www rule, check out the .htaccess files on any open-source CMS, like Drupal or Wordpress, to see some of the best practices.

Comment: Your syntax works perfectly for redirecting to the SSL, thanks. Unfortunately I can accomplish both feats separately but when combining them I find myself stuck in a redirect loop. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Yeah... that's a problem, isn't it. I haven't had to do both at once on any of my sites.

Comment: Yeah, this is the first time i've had it come up as well. I have to force 1 type of URL system so my Jquery posts match the parent url. (ex: if the URL is domain.com jquery has to use domain.com not www.domain.com)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for a couple of my client sites:

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite all http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```