# I install a ssl on my vps,but the domain still has not https

Tags: apache, ssl

I used certbot to call cloudflare's api and installed let's encrypt's SSL certificate for my website. my vps install centos7 and apache ,my website is wordpress
I use cloudflare's strict(full) mode, my website can be opened, but there is no lock pattern in front of the domain name, and it shows "not secure"
I wrote these in the apache file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain.com-acces.log common
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!RC4:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!EXP:+MEDIUM

SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

but nothing changed
what should I do now?

Comment: Does the SSL certificate work when you type `https://` before the domain?

Comment: So you need to force SSL by redirecting `http://` to `https://`.

Comment: I opened port 80 at the same time. Can both ports 80 and 443 be open at the same time?
I write 80 port like this:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain.com-acces.log common
<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: is the 443 port I write on my post is all right? @
Obvious_Grapefruit

Comment: Please refer to this answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923331/9240389

Comment: I install mod_ssl with this `yum -y install mod_ssl`
and it success
but I can not find this `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` on the file
`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: I see that answer and I add `Redirect / https://examole.com/`
and it works !
thankyou very much